# Bash Script to save grep -c results

Tags: bash

I am new to programming altogether and am trying to write my first bash script.

I have a file called `NUMBERS.txt` that has various numbers in it, as such:

```
1000
1001
1001
1000
1002
1001
etc..
```

I would like to write a script to count the occurrence of each number, save it as a variable and print it into a new text file as such:

```
1001= 3
1000= 2
etc..
```

I am completely stuck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 #!/bin/bash

for Count in `grep -c '1000' /NUMBERS.txt `
do
echo 'Count = '${Count}
done

for Count in `grep -c '1001' /NUMBERS.txt `
do
echo 'Count = '${Count}
done
```

Comment: Does it really need to be bash\grep ?

Comment: The best way to do this is `sort NUMBERS.txt | uniq -c`, plus optional post-processing to get the exact format you want. Is there a specific reason you want to "save it as a variable and print it"?

Comment: I want to scan the entire NUMBERS.txt, count the unique numbers, export the count under a custom name into a another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your file is already have one number on each line, it is simpler

```
 for i in `sort -u NUMBERS.txt ` ; do count=`grep -c "$i" NUMBERS.txt ` ; echo "$i=$count" ; done  > your_result.txt
```

or in a different format

```
for i in `sort -u NUMBERS.txt `
do
    count=`grep -c "$i" NUMBERS.txt `
    echo "$i=$count"
done  > your_result.txt
```

As asked by , the performance is not very good. here is a much better one

```
sort NUMBERS.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1,"=",$2}'
```

Basically you go through NUNMBERS.txt twice. The first pass, you get the unique numbers;
The second pass you count the occurrence of each unique number.

Comment: This is horrid for performance.  You don't need to read the file 1000 times like this solution does.

Comment: I provided a better one

Answer (score 4):

Sort the file then count how many times each unique line occurs:

```
sort NUMBERS.txt | uniq -c
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. If you tack on an awk call you get this: `sort NUMBERS.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,"=",$1}'` which prints lines like 1000 = 2

Comment: This is the extensible way to do it. It won't matter if the numbers grow to be 9 digits long (or longer), or are less than 1000.  And the output formatting is trivially handled (as diagnosed in the comment by @twopoint718) if it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best at shell script, but here is a solution that works, using bash and grep -c :

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="./numbers.txt"
OUTPUT="./result.txt"

rm -f ${OUTPUT}

# you might want to change the values
for i in {1000..2000}; do
    for Count in `grep -c ${i} ${INPUT}`; do
    echo "${i} = ${Count}" >> ${OUTPUT}
    done
done
```

Comment: As I'm using the `>>` operator to append each line to the file, if you don't remove it before starting the script, you'll have a file that contains the result twice. Anyway, @John Smith's answer looks much better, as I said, I'm not the best at shell scripting.